# Where/when to call contentOffset on WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm loading a webpage in my `WKWebView` that I need to offset by `y`. I'm calling `webView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, y)` in `func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!)` so that the content is offset as soon as the webpage is finished loading, but sometimes it doesn't offset at all.

In my webpage, I'm displaying a video. The problem is that the height of the video doesn't fit the bounds of the `WKWebView`, unless I offset it. Without changing the actual height of the video in the webpage, where and when should I be calling `contentOffset` to make sure my video is shown appropriately everytime?

There should be no black space above Aloe Blacc.

[image]